# ResourceBundle getting wrong ListResourceBundle (by Locale)

Tags: java, bundle

There are 2 classes:

```
public class MyListResourceBundle_de extends ListResourceBundle {
    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][] {
                { "hello", "Hallo" }, { "world", "Welt" }
        };
    }
}

public class MyListResourceBundle extends ListResourceBundle {
    @Override
    protected Object[][] getContents() {
        return new Object[][] {
                { "hello", "Hello" }, { "world", "World" }
        };
    }
}
```

When trying to get the bundle for locale *en* it always gets the one for *de* not the default one (`MyListResourceBundle`):

```
public class MyTest {
    private static ResourceBundle bundle;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        bundle = ResourceBundle.getBundle("test.MyListResourceBundle", new Locale("en"));
    }

    @Test
    public void testLocale() {
        for (String key : bundle.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(key + " -> " + bundle.getString(key));
        }

        assertEquals("en", bundle.getLocale().toString());
    }
}
```

The output is the following:

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running test.MyTest
hello -> Hallo
world -> Welt
Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.067 sec <<< FAILURE!

Results :

Failed tests:   testLocale(test.MyTest): expected:<[en]> but was:<[de]>

Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0
```

Is this the correct behaviour or do I misunderstood something?

Answer (score 0):

Is En-US or en-GB you want? I think is that that is missing in your code..

try to instanciate the Locale like this:

```
new Locale("en", "US");
```

Comment: No, same result. If there's no `MyListResourceBundle_en` it should use `MyListResourceBundle` instead. But it always uses `MyListResourceBundle_de` even if I specify `en` as locale.